# Use div tag to divide to 4 area in a page

Tags: html, css

I use inside of div tag, 4 div tags to divide to 4 equal areas using following tag.
Is there any other way to divide or improve this division

```html
<div style="width: 689px; margin-left: 215px; margin-top: 0px; float: none; height: 502px;"> 
             <div style="width: 336px; height: 251px; display: inline-block; float: left;">
             </div>
             <div style="width: 336px; height: 251px">
             </div>
             <div style="width: 336px; height: 251px; display: inline-block; float: left;">
             </div>
             <div style="width: 336px; height: 251px">
             </div>

         </div>
```

Comment: you can remove the `display:inline-block;` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<div style="width: 50%; height: 50%">` for inner divs.

There are no other improvements i can suggest you about styles.

In the other hand, if you want to see divs while designing, i can suggest you to assign them temporary background colors like:

```html
<div style="width: 689px; margin-left: 215px; margin-top: 0px; float: none; height: 502px;background-color:gray"> 
             <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: inline-block; float: left;background-color:yellow">
             </div>
             <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%;background-color:red;float: left">
             </div>
             <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: inline-block; float: left;background-color:green">
             </div>
             <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%;background-color:blue;float:left">
             </div>
         </div>
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to background colors, i realised that your floating divs hide other ones. You should add `float:left` for all inner divs.

Answer (score 1):

Is this your desired effect?

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
}
.container div {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
    <div style="background:red">A</div>
    <div style="background:blue">B</div>
    <div style="background:lime">C</div>
    <div style="background:cyan">D</div>
</div>
```

Or is this?

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.container div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
    <div style="background:red">A</div>
    <div style="background:blue">B</div>
    <div style="background:lime">C</div>
    <div style="background:cyan">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Leo Deng  I want divide page to 4 equal squares to cover full page